# how to get the cpu serial number

Tags: node.js, typescript, serial-number

I am trying to get the cpu serial number for the authentication. I use serial-number package to get the serial number but I cannot store the serial in other variable.

```
import * as serialNumber from 'serial-number';
var num = null;
serialNumber(function (err, value) {
 num = value;
 console.log(value);
});

console.log(num);
```

Comment: The call is asynchronous. You have to put your whole code inside the function. That's how asynchronous coding works.

Comment: adding to answer above, `console.log(num)` is executed even before the callback `function (err, value)...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so instead of storing what you can do is directly pass the value into another function, like this:

```
var serialNumber = require('serial-number');

//if authentication is true
function ifTrue(value){
    console.log(true, value); 
}
//if authentication is false
function ifFalse(value){
    console.log(false, value);
}
//function for authentication
function authentication(value){
    //do something with the value 
    //value can be accessed within this block only
    console.log(value);

    //authentication logic
    if(value==="xyz"){
        ifTrue(value);
    }
    else{
        ifFalse(value);
    }
}

serialNumber(function (err, value) {
 authentication(value)
});
```

Output:

5CD24118HT

false 5CD24118HT